# How to set BackColor using RGB values in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, rgb

How can I set the [BackColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.backcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) of a Button using RGB values? This doesn't work:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonUpdate" runat="server" 
            Text="Update" BackColor="rgb(112, 207, 131)" 
            OnClick="ButtonUpdate_Click" />
```

Comment: Color backColor= Color.FromArgb(102,227, 142); shoudl do the trick

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying in source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `rgb(` and `)`:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonUpdate" runat="server" 
            Text="Update" BackColor="112, 207, 131" 
            OnClick="ButtonUpdate_Click" />
```

All properties of type [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx) (including BackColor) support a variety of possible formats. The parsing logic is implemented in [ColorConverter.ConvertFrom](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Drawing/R/ba873a1502c67c74.html).

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
ButtonUpdate.backColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F9DA00");
```

Comment: I was searching in source code and wanted to use RGB, thanks.

Comment: @hqtunes.com:- Ok,  you didnt mention that initially. Anyways you can proceed with Michael solution :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <asp:Button ID="ButtonUpdate" runat="server" 
Text="Update" style="background:rgb(112, 207, 131)" 
OnClick="ButtonUpdate_Click"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ButtonUpdate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(112, 207, 131);`